# Multiprocess Pool / Multiprocessing Pool gets stuck on ubuntu

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, ubuntu, multiprocessing

I have a script which is using the Multiprocess(ing) Pool function. On windows, when I start the script, my processor goes up to 100% utilization (as expected) and the sequential version also runs without any problems.
When deploying on ubuntu, the pool seems to get stuck after the first process iteration and the processor utilization is at 99.5% Idle.

I already used suggested solutions like:

```
set_start_method("spawn")
```

and

```
maxtasksperchild=1
```

Logging module does not work in both cases (but it is a secondary problem).

The starting code looks like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.set_start_method("spawn")
    logging.basicConfig(filename='seasonality.log', level=logging.DEBUG)

    EOD_Hist = eod_historical.PullEOD(apikey, 'json')

    ticker = EOD_Hist.get_index_components_list(index)

    def main(ticker_):
        start_year = 1970
        start = '2023-01-01'
        end = '2023-12-31'
        logging.debug(f'{datetime.now()}: {ticker_} FULL TASKS STARTED - params:  start_year = {start_year} / start = {start} / end = {end}')
        hist, iter_range = raw_data(start_year, ticker_)
        start_df, end_df, performance_df, average_perf_df, median_perf_df, perf_stdv, max_draw_down_df, hit_ratio = period_iter(start, end, hist, iter_range)
        df = create_df(start_df, end_df, performance_df, average_perf_df, median_perf_df, perf_stdv, max_draw_down_df, hit_ratio)
        helper_functions.write_df_to_database(mongoip, mongouser, mongopw, mongotable, ticker, df)
        logging.debug(f'{datetime.now()}: {ticker_} FULL TASKS ENDED - length_df_written = {df}')
        return f'{ticker} done'

    pool = mp.Pool(os.cpu_count(), maxtasksperchild=1)                         # Create a multiprocessing Pool
    result = pool.map(main, ticker)
    print(result)
```

The called functions should work properly, as the sequential version is working fine. And I see the API calls are processed correctly as my daily amount of credits shrinks.

Comment: Sometimes some libraries have problems with multiprocessing. For example, I had problem with tkinter backend in matplotlib and when changed the backend problem disappeared. I suggest to comment everything and uncomment line by line to narrow down what causes multiprocessing to get stuck.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I think I will have to do this. My guess - it is the logging tool which causes the problem. The rest is only pandas, requests, numpy whiich I expect work with multiprocessing.

Comment: `mask_tasks_per_child=1` is probably slowing you down rather than helping you.  You probably also want to use `with mp.Pool(....) as pool: ` so that the pool is cleaned up properly before you exit.